# problems installing sql server 2008 on windows server 2012

Tags: installation, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a 64bit OS, **Windows 2012 Server R2** and I'm having trouble installing *SQL SERVER 2008/R2* on that system.

Apparently, `.NET 4.5` is installed but SQL SERVER requires `.NET 3.5 SP1` which **WILL NOT** install either through stand alone download file or through Web Installer. Nor can I install PHP Manager for IIS on this system.

What's important is that I need to install the DB and I'm at a loss.

Comment: .NET 3.5 is a Feature of Windows 2012, add it via Roles/Features, not via a downloaded installer.

Comment: As Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 said: .NET must be installed through the Roles/Features wizard. Any other method doesn't work or, even worse, can damage the Windows installation on the server. (There are some 'hacked'  installers floating on the internet that claim to work on server 2012 and later, but stay away from those. They are bogus, can break things and in most cases contain malware too!)

Comment: Tonny, I've tried that but "No Joy!"  Through the Web Platform Installer and Roles/Features.  It's frustrating.

Comment: @PeterTheAngularDude use server manager, not the web installer. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/how-to-add-roles-to-a-windows-server-2012-computer/ .net3.5 is gonna be under features.

Comment: Nazard. Thank you pal, but I did that already. It error's out... Let me try again and I'll send the error to you.  OK: So here's what I get:  Do you need to specify an alternate source path? One or more installation selections are missing source files on the destination server. The server will try to get missing source files from Windows Update, or from a location that is specified by Group Policy. You can also click the “Specify an alternate source path” link on this page to provide a valid location for the source files.  This is a 1and1 Dedicated Server. Maybe I'll call 1and1 Tech Support..